# Automatic upcast of TypedDict to Dict[str, Any]

Tags: python, python-typing

I was surprised when mypy rejected the following example:

```py
from typing import Any, Dict, TypedDict


class Task(TypedDict):
    task_id: str
    title: str


def test(arg: Task) -> Dict[str, Any]:
  return arg
```

Task ought to be a subtype of `Dict[str, Any]` but for some reason mypy doesn't think so.

Comment: Should it? What if the recipient tried to access keys other than task_id or title? See https://peps.python.org/pep-0589/#type-consistency

Comment: So, for `TypedDict` types, structural compatibility is used, and for the purposes of static analysis, a `TypeDict` is never compatible with a `Dict` (i.e. a `TypeDict` is never a subtype of `Dict` and vice-versa, see [the mypy docs](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/more_types.html?highlight=TypedDict#typeddict)). I would just around this by use `typing.cast` though, which should be safe

Comment: @jonrsharpe a downcast from `Dict` to (a particular) `TypedDict` would be unsafe but an upcast from a `TypedDict` to a `Dict` wouldn't, as we're weakening the guarantee. We're going from "a dict with these specific keys" to "a dict".

Answer (score 1):

`mypy` [type invariance](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generics.html#variance-of-generics) for this case has no great documented alternative unfortunately:

```py
import configparser
from typing import Mapping
from typing_extensions import TypedDict

TD = TypedDict("TD",{"data": str})

def do_stuff(data: TD):
    config = configparser.ConfigParser()
    data_as_mapping: Mapping = data

    # as Mapping there is no mypy error
    config.read_dict(data_as_mapping)
```

Because of [invariance](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generics.html#variance-of-generics), regardless of the type of a `TypedDict`'s `values` being a sub-type of `Any`, it unfortunately doesn't make your `TypedDict` a sub-type of `Mapping[str, Any]`. But, your `TypedDict` is still a sub-type of just `Mapping` (without the higher-kinded types: `[str, Any]`)

This [topic has been discussed yet remains closed](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/4976#issuecomment-460971843). Despite a developer at one point suggesting to *special case* `Mapping[str, Any]` so that `TypedDict` was always a sub-type of it, they later in the same thread gave reasons not to do so.

So unfortunately the only documented way forward, aside from `cast`, is to give up on your `TypedDict` and instead treat it as type `Mapping`, which of course forfeits some type safety.

Answer (score -1):

In **mypy** `TypedDict` is incompatible with `dict`, see discussion in this [issue](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/4976).

Use `Mapping[str, Any]` instead:

```py
from typing import Any, Mapping, TypedDict


class Task(TypedDict):
    task_id: str
    title: str


def test(arg: Task) -> Mapping[str, Any]:
    return arg
```

Comment: This is bad advice when working with 3rd party code bases. I can't make their dict[str,any] magically into Mapping.